# Successful login with iscsiadm on target still doesn't create block device

Tags: iscsi

I've set up an experiment to test iscsitarget and initiator, which at some point worked. Later, I turned the setup back on and much to my dismay, the initiator machine stopped making block devices for its successful logins. As far as I know, I haven't changed anything on either machine.

Some details:

```
# iscsiadm -m node --login
Logging in to [iface: default, target: iqn.2010-12.nl.ytec.arbiter:arbiter.lun1, portal: 10.0.0.1,3260]
Logging in to [iface: default, target: iqn.2010-12.nl.ytec.arbiter:arbiter.lun2, portal: 10.0.0.1,3260]
Login to [iface: default, target: iqn.2010-12.nl.ytec.arbiter:arbiter.lun1, portal: 10.0.0.1,3260]: successful
Login to [iface: default, target: iqn.2010-12.nl.ytec.arbiter:arbiter.lun2, portal: 10.0.0.1,3260]: successful
```

Sessions:

```
# iscsiadm -m session
tcp: [3] 10.0.0.1:3260,1 iqn.2010-12.nl.ytec.arbiter:arbiter.lun1
tcp: [4] 10.0.0.1:3260,1 iqn.2010-12.nl.ytec.arbiter:arbiter.lun2
```

Netstat:

```
# netstat -n -p|grep 3260
tcp        0      0 10.0.0.2:48719          10.0.0.1:3260           ESTABLISHED 1078/iscsid     
tcp        0      0 10.0.0.2:48718          10.0.0.1:3260           ESTABLISHED 1078/iscsid
```

/var/log/syslog doesn't give errors:

```
Jan 27 11:41:49 vmnode001 kernel: [  378.041749] scsi7 : iSCSI Initiator over TCP/IP
Jan 27 11:41:49 vmnode001 kernel: [  378.044180] scsi8 : iSCSI Initiator over TCP/IP
```

lsscsi doesn't show my devices:

```
[0:0:1:0]    cd/dvd  TSSTcorp DVD-ROM TS-L333A D100  /dev/sr0
[4:0:0:0]    disk    ATA      Hitachi HUA72105 A74A  -       
[4:0:1:0]    disk    ATA      Hitachi HUA72105 A74A  -       
[4:1:0:0]    disk    Dell     VIRTUAL DISK     1028  /dev/sda
```

And there are no block devices in /dev for it:

```
# ls -1 /dev/sd*
/dev/sda
/dev/sda1
/dev/sda2
/dev/sda3
/dev/sda4
```

I tried loading all scsi kernel modules I could find, but that doesn't seem to be the problem.

I reall don't get this; it used to work. I found people with similar problems ([here](http://forums11.itrc.hp.com/service/forums/questionanswer.do?threadId=1428503) and [here](http://nixcraft.com/xen/16311-no-scsi-block-device-created-iscsiadm-xen-domu-dom0.html)) but no solution.

Initiator is Debian Sqeeuze (testing), target is Debian Lenny (stable). iscsitarget is 0.4.16+svn162-3.1+lenny1, open-iscsi (initiator) is 2.0.871.3-2squeeze1. Target kernel: 2.6.26-2-amd64, initiator kernel: 2.6.32-5-amd64

Answer (score 1):

change name `iqn.2010-12.nl.ytec.arbiter:arbiter.lun1` to `iqn.2010-12.nl.ytec.arbiter:arbiter.blabla.lun1`

Comment: It did work with that name, so I don't really know why that would fix it. However, I would try it, but I reinstalled the machine and gave it a different purpose :(

Comment: Someone willing to elaborate on the reason for this :D?

Comment: This answer didn't describe detail about reason why to add "blabla", and I met same problem, but this answer not work.

Answer (score 0):

I found one wrong point to product this problem on the FreeNas system. I did not add "Associated Targets" between "Targets" and "Extends". Maybe, you can check this point to find out solution, good luck.

Comment: That was quite a while ago. I never took it into production, actually.